# Any search tool for LXDE menu?

Tags: launcher, search, lxde, zeitgeist

I just installed lxde to boot into when laptop is using battery, but I really miss at least a simple search feature, I am used to Unity so I find myself losing too much time navigating on the menus, given that the LXDE menu is just a list with a basic categorization. I would prefer to avoid creating shortcuts everywhere if possible.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Forget about that, there's nothing like that for the LXDE menu, use Synapse.

Install it from the terminal: `sudo apt-get install synapse`

Synapse review with screenshots 
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/11/synapse-gnome-do-launcher-app-review-ubuntu

The correct, fancy name for it is **semantic launcher** BTW :)

Other related stuff:
Zeitgeist - indexing tool used by Synapse
Gnome Do - another launcher similar to Synapse, older

Comment: I can't find it in the repositories now. Is it discontinued or what?

Comment: it sounds kinda heavyweight.  will it run ok on old hardware (the reason i'm running lubuntu/lxde)?

Comment: You have to add a PPA to run synapse on Ubuntu 15.04: http://askubuntu.com/a/624696/34298

Comment: the zeitgeist domain that is in use has expired and been taken over by a domainer, so my worry is that all the external stuff doesn't work anymore (the externally referenced plugins). Kupfer (noted below) is more recently updated.

Comment: When I installed synapse on my lubuntu 18.04 via terminal, I could open it but not search anything

Answer (score 5):

Kupfer provides a simple menu searcher activated from a global keyboard shortcut.

```
sudo apt-get install kupfer
```

By default you show Kupfer using the global keyboard shortcut Ctrl+Space.

https://kupferlauncher.github.io/

A quick video review can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MPVpfMSMYXQ).

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...

Comment: Can somebody update the answer with correct link?

Comment: Is there a way to make it show several results? For example typing 'chrom' and seeing Chromium and Chrome

Answer (score 4):

XFCE provides an excellent app finder. You can install it with

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4-appfinder
```

Comment: doesn't it need the xfce4 panel in order to function?

Comment: @cipricus It seems to need only the `xfce4-appfinder` and `xfconf` packages and some libs, total 1 MB download and 5 MB installed

Comment: @golimar - Thanks. No need for such tools in 18.10.

Answer (score 1):

Lubuntu 18.10 with LXQt desktop has two search tools by default:

- The *Applications Menu*

[image]

- The Runner (`lxqt-runner`)

[image]

Their shortcuts are configurable, including the "Super" key; under *Preferences>LXQt Settings>LXQt Configurations settings>Shortcut keys*.

Comment: never heard of LXQt, is it replacing LXDE or is it an alternative?

Comment: @golimar - Not only it is the new default desktop of Lubuntu in 18.10 and probably after that, but it represents a change also in that it is a Qt desktop. If you are interested I have posted a number of questions and answers on LXQt on both askubuntu and Unix&Linux, you can search with "cipricus" and "lxqt". If you are using Lubuntu 18.04 and want to use 18.10 I would recommend a clean re-install because of the gtk-qt discrepancies.

Comment: @golimar - I guess it is at least as light as LXDE by default with openbox as window manager. (I prefer a more heavy customization myself, with kwin as window manager and dolphin as file manager, entailing the installation of the Plasma desktop  - which I do not use, but which is installed). - The two search tools mentioned above come by default.

Comment: @user47206 unfortunately LXQT is not "at least as light as" LXDE even as of Oct 2020.