# Is there a shell-independent search tool like the Unity's Dash?

Tags: software-recommendation, unity-dash, search, lxde, zeitgeist

The only thing I will miss after moving to LXDE from Unity will be the Unity Dash. Its functionality, not the piss-poor performance that is. So here's my question. I know there is **synapse** but AFAIK it only returns text, without multiple large-sized thumbnails of files etc.

**I'm looking for a tool:**

1. that uses relatively large area to present results
2. with thumbnailing capability
3. with immediate presentation of recently used files and apps, preferably

**Hence I do not look for *any launcher***. Point's no. 1 and 2 make for sufficient replacement. Please don't be afraid to answer *'No, there are none'* if there no alternatives similar to Unity Dash or Gnome Shell Activities exist.

Related question: [Any search tool for LXDE menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/203851/any-search-tool-for-lxde-menu)

Comment: I am using synapse with the "Doish" theme.  Thumbnails do exist (I typed to search for a recently opened picture file and the preview showed).  Is there something else that this is missing?

Comment: @iveand Please refer to the updated question content. ('that uses relatively large area to present results', ... ).

Comment: I am afraid I don't know any tool which thumbnails. There was a tool called `sezen` by Zeitgeist devs but they deprecated it in favour of Unity Dash, GNOME Shell overview and Synapse. Sezen used to show thumbnails IIRC

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there are no alternatives that present results like Unity's Dash nor as convenient. You can, however, use one of the semantic launchers available for linux:

- Old but gold: Gnome Do
- Better and newer: Kupfer
- My favorite (I am using it all the time, much faster than the dash): Synapse

All of them are in the USC.

Here is a link to synapse: [USC LINK](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/synapse/)

Comment: Guys, please note that I'm looking for a tool with thumbnailing.

Comment: Hey Bucic, if I remember this in two month's I would be quite interested in looking if I am able to create a theme with bigger thumbnails...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [Launchy](http://www.launchy.net/about.php) which is a small utility that indexes all your programs and documents so that you can launch them easily with just a few keyboard shortcuts.
[image]

You can grab the `.deb` from [HERE](http://www.launchy.net/download.php).

Comment: Guys, please note that I'm looking for a tool with thumbnailing.