# Run synapse (or alternative) on Lubuntu 15.04

Tags: lxde, synapse

On Lununtu 15.04 I installed synapse via PPA:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:synapse-core/testing
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install synapse
```

[image]

Source: http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-synapse-0-2-99-on-ubuntu-15-04-ubuntu-14-10-ubuntu-14-04-and-derivatives/

It seems to run, but it crashes the moment I enter any letter into the window.

How can I make this run or is there an alternative on Lubuntu with lxde?

Comment: Try a stable release from `ppa:synapse-core/ppa` and remove the testing PPA. (Most easily done by replacing the PPA path in /etc/apt/sources.list or a file in sources.list.d, followed by `apt-get update`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it would suffice to start the execute-command from your menu with

> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>F1</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove synapse with

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge synapse
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/synapse-core*
```

and add the non-testing ppa:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:synapse-core/ppa
```

as long as synapse is not in the [repository](http://ppa.launchpad.net/synapse-core/ppa/ubuntu/dists/) for vivid, I need to replace `vivid` with `trusty`:

```
sudo su
sed s/vivid/trusty/g /etc/apt/sources.list.d/synapse-core-ubuntu-ppa-vivid.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/synapse-core-ubuntu-ppa-trusty.list
rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/synapse-core-ubuntu-ppa-vivid.list
```

and reinstall synapse:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install synapse
```