# Lubuntu: application search application

Tags: lubuntu

Is there an application search application like the Ubuntu dash or Windows start menu where I can insert an application name, press ENTER and then, the searched application will be opened? It should be fast, reliable, easy to access and also work fine on netbooks.

Comment: there are some alternatives indeed http://askubuntu.com/q/203851/29595. @kos the problem is that the user is using Lubuntu (see title of question, and tag)

Comment: @dadexix86  Feeling a bit dumb now. Thanks.

Comment: @kos As dadexix86 correctly states, I am using Lubuntu and Lubuntu doesn't use Dash. The Ubuntu Unity interface, of which Dash is a part, is too heavy for my netbook. It doesn't work smoothly.

Comment: @dadexix86 Thank you. The link helps a lot. I decided for xfce4-appfinder. It's exactly what I was looking for. :)

Comment: I wish you'd give `kupfer` a look as well (also mentioned in dadexix86's link). It's pretty powerful **and** light.